# Adding an image path to a filter in css by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I have the following for my site's background to be scaled when in Internet Explorer:

```
#background{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}
```

That works great, but I need to change the image path to a variable that comes from javascript, from an array with several backgrounds. With a radom number I'm chosing the background everytime the site loads.

To do that I'm doing:

```
#background{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='<script>document.write(background[rn]);</script>', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='<script>document.write(background[rn]);</script>', sizingMethod='scale')";}
```

But this is not working. The scaling does not work anymore.

Why? What's wrong with it? How would you make it work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
<script>
document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">\n#background{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + background[rn] + "', sizingMethod='scale' \n-ms-filter: \"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + background[rn] + "', sizingMethod='scale')\";}\n</style>");
</script>
```

In your example you were trying to insert a script tag inside quotes, this is not possible as it would just be interpreted as a string and not a script.

Comment: This would require to put the `script` element inside a `style` element, which is not possible. You'll need to "write" the `style` element, too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this problem you cannot dynamically change this attribute when it is being applied to the body tag.